# Converting a single txt file to arff file automatically

Tags: weka, text-classification, arff

I have a single .txt file including a lot of Arabic text, and I want to convert this file to an .arff file automatically, so I can use it in Weka to get rules from it.

As my Professor requested I need to have 30 attributes, and each attribute should have all words in the text file, and each line of data will include real sentences, but separated to words using `,` and if the sentence includes less than 30 words, the remaining part will be filled with `?`.

The arff file should look like the following:

```
@relation RelName

@attribute 'x1'{*will include all words in the text file*}
@attribute 'x2'{*will include all words in the text file*}
.
.
.
@attribute 'x30'{*will include all words in the text file*}

@data
Wordx,Wordy,Wordz,Wordq,Wordw,?,?,?,?,?...................,? //till 30 word
.
.
.
.
```

and so on

So is there anyway to generate this format .arff file from a single .txt file automatically? Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

You can use arff 0.9. Works well with python 2.x and 3.x.

EG:

import arff
data = [[1,2,3], [10, 20, 30]]
arff.dump('result.arff', data, relation="test", names=['one', 'two', 'three'])

The command is going to create a relation test with three attributes 'one', 'two' and 'three'. First column will contain 1,10. Second column contains 2,20. Third column contains 3,30.